# Jump into Chrome debugger from Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, debugging

When I place the command
    debugger;
within my Angular code, it is not jumping into the Chrome debugger when it hits this line.  I just passes over it.

How do you jump into the Chrome debugger from within your Angular code?

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Do you have the dev tools open? Is the debugger statement used in javascript code? Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes, I have dev tools open.  The debugger statement is in my Javascript code.